# Equivalence of two approaches to transverse measures for a foliation

Tags: measure-theory, noncommutative-geometry, foliations

Suppose that $(V,F)$ is a foliated manifold. There are three equivalent approaches to the notion of *transverse measure* as described in [this](https://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf) book (see pages 65-69). I would like to understand the last line in the section 5$\alpha$ where it is stated that ,,one easily checks, as in the case of flows, that $\Lambda$ satisfies definition 2''. So the context is as follows: one starts with a closed current $C$ (of degree $=dim F$) positive in the leaf direction and with the help of this current defines a measure $\mu_U$ (locally on $U$, the domain of the foliation chart) on the set of plaques by the fromula 
$$\langle C,\omega \rangle=\int \Big(\int_{\pi} \omega \Big)d\mu_U(\pi). $$
Once we have this measure we can define $\Lambda(B):=\int Card(B \cap \pi)d\mu_{U}(\pi)$ for any Borel transversal $B$ (i.e. Borel subset $B \subset V$ such that for each leaf $L$ of the foliation $B \cap L$ is at most countable.

> > Why $\Lambda$ satisfies $\Lambda(B)=\Lambda(\psi(B))$ for any Borel injection $\psi$ which preserves leaves.

My guess is that it should somehow follow from the condition of $C$ being closed but I'm not sure how to perform the calculations (for example one problem which I encountered is that $\Lambda$ is defined locally and I don;t see how to pass from $U$ to another foliation chart $U'$ (which may happen for general $\psi$).